# Paula goes to work three days a week, with $\frac14$ chance to take the bus. What is the expected number of tmes she takes the bus?

Tags: probability

> Paula goes to work three days a week. On any day, the probability that
>   she goes on a red bus is $\frac14$.
>
> (a) Write down the expected number of times that Paula goes to work on
>   a red bus in one week.

I think the solution should be $\frac{3}{7} . \frac{1}{4} = \frac{3}{28}$. But the right answer is $0.75$ .

Comment: Why divide by $7$? The expected number is added, not averaged, over the days of the week.

Comment: Got that. You're right. Thanks. @Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability that Paula will ride a red bus is $\frac{1}{4}$. Using multiplication rule, you multiply this value to the number of times she works in a week which is 3, thus the answer should be

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{4} \cdot 3 = \frac{3}{4}.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify how much probability knowledge you have (I think IB is high school level), so I propose an "intuitive" approach.

The chance that you she takes a red bus is $1/4$. We know she only goes to work **three** times per week. In other words, we have three opportunities for success.

So, the expected number of times she takes the bus during a week is
$$3\cdot \frac{1}{4} = \frac{3}{4}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The question asks for the number of times that Paula goes to work **in one week**. Multiply your answer by 7 to get 3/4. By the way, how did you get from (3/7) * (1/4) to 11/38?

Comment: Corrected. I just wrote previous questions's answer. Sorry.

Comment: I think you mean to get rid of 7, I need to multiply. As Ian says, I need to multiply 1/4 with 3.

Comment: Your answer was (3/7) * (1/4), because you erroneously divided by 7. Now if you multiply your answer by 7, you get the correct answer, 3 * (1/4).